# Deleting a line from a txt file in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, text-files

Is there a way to remove a line from the end of a .txt file from Objective-C? I can't seem to find anything on manipulating text files from Objective-C, only reading them into a NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered changing your data model to a plist?  Plists are more easily read/written into/from NSDictionaries.

Otherwise, I think the only way is to read the file into a `NSString`, separate into a component NSArray by splitting on `\n`, remove the object at index n, write back into a string by joining with component `\n`, then writing back to the file.